# how to use each function to get attr of each element with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

html is

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><img src="ex.jpg" id="image" class="edit" name="n1"></td>
<td><img src="ex.jpg" id="image" class="edit" name="n2"></td>
<td><img src="ex.jpg" id="image" class="edit" name="n3"></td>
<td><img src="ex.jpg" id="image" class="edit" name="n4"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Jquery code is:

```
$(".edit").click(function() {

$("#image").each(function(){

alert(this.name);

});

});
```

Here is, it only alerts one name, i mean just alerts "n1".

How can i alert name attr. of each element ?

Thank you

Comment: Sorry @Ahmet vardar, but I rolled back to the original question. Because is harder for the first-time readers to understand the problem if you change the basics in the question without mentioning it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have multiple elements with the same ID (hence the name: ID). If you do, `#image` **always** matches only the first element with the given ID (in your case the #n1 image). You can, however, add multiple classes to an element:

HTML:

```
<img class="edit image" name="foobar" />
```

JS:

```
$(".image").each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

`this` in this context is the plain DOM element. You first have to change it into an jQuery object (`var $that = $(this)`) before you can use `.attr()` on it.

Comment: Perhaps, but in any case the `id` attributes should be changed to `image-1`, `image-2`, etc. or removed.

Comment: i deleted id, and tried as you said but it alerts undefined now for a reason

Comment: i fixed it, i dont need each function to do it, removed it and it works great

Answer (score 0):

```
var title = $("img").attr("name");
alert (title);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is actually invalid; no two elements are allowed to have the same `id`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that id of element should be unique so jQuery may not try to get all of them (so you only have one element).

My suggestion is to change the id of each.

In case you can't do that for want ever reason, try this:

```
$("img[id='image']").each(function(){

alert(this.name);
// Or alert($(this).attr("name"));

});
```

I didn't test it so sorry if there is some mistake.

Hope this helps.